# HTML form with confirmation before submission

Tags: javascript, html, form, dom

I'm creating a website about an auto show that the user is going to. I'm collecting input from them via textboxes, check boxes, radio buttons, etc. I'm presenting them with a confirmation that the information they entered is correct. Is the way I'm doing this the most efficient, injecting the HTML into the website via JavaScript?

**online_form.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Online Form - BA</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="external/style.css">
        <script src="external/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- NAV START -->
        <hr>
        <a href="index.html">Main Page</a> - <a href="online_form.html">Online Form</a> - <a href="special.html">Specialty Car</a>
        <hr>
        <!-- NAV END -->
        <h2>Complete this online form to get into the Ann Arbor Auto Show for <i>FREE</i></h2>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <label>Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="name"><br>
                <label>Age:</label>
                <input type="text" id="age"><br>
                <label>Email:</label>
                <input type="text" id="email"><br>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <h3>What is your reason for attending the Ann Arbor Auto Show?</h3>
                <input type="radio" name="reason" value="cars">I like cars<br>
                <input type="radio" name="reason" value="been_before">I've been here before<br>
                <input type="radio" name="reason" value="friend">A friend told me<br>
                <input type="radio" name="reason" value="other">Other<br>
                <p>If other, please explain:</p>
                <textarea rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <h3>What color cars do you like?</h3>
                <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="red">Red<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="blue">Blue<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="green">Green<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="orange">Orange<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="yellow">Yellow<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="purple">Purple<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="black">Black<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="white">White<br>
            </fieldset>
            <button type="button" onclick="checkInformation()">Submit</button>
            <button type="reset">Reset</button>
            <div id="conformation"></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
function Form() {
    this._name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    this.age = document.getElementById('age').value;
    this.email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    this.conformation = document.getElementById('conformation');

    /*
    * Reset this.conformation if user clicks `no` button
    */
    this.conformation.innerHTML = "";

    this.response = '<h3>Is this information correct?</h3>\n';
    this.response += '<p>Name: ' + this._name + '</p>\n';
    this.response += '<p>Age: ' + this.age + '</p>\n';
    this.response += '<p>Email: ' + this.email + '</p>\n';
    this.response += '<button type="button" onclick="yes()">Yes</button>';
    this.response += '<button type="reset" onclick="no()">No</button>';

    this.send_conformation = function() {
        this.conformation.style.display = "block";
        this.conformation.innerHTML = this.response;
    }
}

var form;

function checkInformation() {
    form = new Form();
    form.send_conformation();
}

function yes() { /* To be implemented */}

function no() {
    var conf = document.getElementById('conformation');
    conf.style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `document.getElementById`s with a `forEach` and the `this.response` lines with [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to keep the code [DRY](https://dzone.com/articles/is-your-code-dry-or-wet) :

```
function Form () {

    ["_name", "age", "email", "confirmation"].forEach(key => {
        const id = key.replace(/^_/, ''); // removes the _ in the beginning
        this[key] = document.getElementById(id).value;
    });

    /*
    * Reset this.conformation if user clicks `no` button
    */

    this.conformation.innerHTML = "";

    this.response = `
        <h3>Is this information correct?</h3>\n
        <p>Name: ${this._name}</p>\n
        <p>Age: ${this.age}</p>\n
        <p>Email: ${this.email}</p>\n
        <button type="button" onclick="yes()">Yes</button>
        <button type="reset" onclick="no()">No</button>`;

    this.send_conformation = function() {
        this.conformation.style.display = "block";
        this.conformation.innerHTML = this.response;
    }
}

var form;

function checkInformation () {
    form = new Form();
    form.send_conformation();
}

function yes { /* To be implemented */}

function no {
    document.getElementById('conformation').style.display = "none";    
}
```